# How do I store a file using multer and get the new changed name

Tags: express, multer

This is the storage code where I set a name. How do i store and access the same name in my post request

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage(
        {
            destination: 'uploads',
            filename: function ( req, file, cb ) {
                cb( null, file.originalname+ '-' + Date.now()+""+expressSession._id+".png");
            }
        }
    );
```

The filename below gives a different name since timestamp changes

```
router.post('/upload', [verifyToken,upload.single('uploadFile')], function (req, res, next) {
    // req.file is the `avatar` file
  
    let filename =  req.file.originalname+'-' + Date.now()+""+expressSession._id+".png"
    console.log(filename );
   
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.file` has a property `filename`. this is the name of the saved file on disk.
there is another property `path`, gives you the absolute path to the file.